# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider when try delete a record

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I am going to delete a record in my asp.net mvc project by using angular js 1.3.13.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees track by $index">
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{emp.EmployeeId}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{emp.EmployeeName}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{emp.Address}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{emp.EmailId}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" 
                   ng-click="delFn($index)"
                   class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

My controller.js code

```
app.controller("EmpCtrl", function ($scope, EmployeeService) {

GetAllEmployee();

function GetAllEmployee() {

    var getAllEmployee = EmployeeService.getEmployee();
    getAllEmployee.then(function (emp) {
        $scope.employees = emp.data;
    }, function () {
        alert('Data not found');
    });
}
    $scope.delFn = function (index) {
        var response = confirm('Delete this Employee?');
        if (response) {
           $scope.employees.splice(index, 1);
           EmployeeService.deleteEmployee(index);
        }
     }
});
```

In my service.js, I have

```
    app.service("EmployeeService", function ($http,id) {
    this.getEmployee = function () {
        return $http.get("/Employee/GetAllEmployee");
    };

    this.deleteEmployee = function () {
        var url = "/Employee/DeleteEmployee/" + id;
        $http.delete(url)
            .success(function (result) {
                alert("Delete Successfully");
            })
            .error(function () {
                alert("Something wrong!");
            })
            .then(function () {
                window.location = '#/';
            })
    }
});
```

In my asp.net controller, I Have the delete method

```
 [HttpDelete]
    public void DeleteEmployee(int id)
    {
       // blah
    }
```

But I get the error when debugging it in chrome.

> angular.min.js:102 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/unpr?p0=idProvider%20%3C-%20id%20%3C-%20EmployeeService

So would you please advise me what is wrong?

Comment: can you check if you have service.js path in the index.html? that error usually indicates that you did not put path to file in script tag

Comment: @OlegMarkoff, I have the path in `_Layout.cshtml`. So it should be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `id` argument from the service construction function to the `deleteEmployee` function:

```
    //REMOVE `id` argument
    //app.service("EmployeeService", function ($http,id) {
    app.service("EmployeeService", function ($http) {
    this.getEmployee = function () {
        return $http.get("/Employee/GetAllEmployee");
    };

    //ADD `id` here
    //this.deleteEmployee = function () {
    this.deleteEmployee = function (id) {
        var url = "/Employee/DeleteEmployee" + id;
        return $http.delete(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                alert("Delete Successfully");
                return response;
            })
            .catch(function (errorResponse) {
                alert("Something wrong!");
                throw errorResponse;
            })
            .then(function () {
                window.location = '#/';
            })
    }
});
```

From the [error message link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=idProvider%20%3C-%20id%20%3C-%20EmployeeService):

> ```
> Unknown provider: idProvider <- id <- EmployeeService
> ```

The injector was erroneously trying to inject a service named `id`.

Comment: But in my controller.js, I have to pass id in. `EmployeeService.deleteEmployee(index)`. If you move the id inside the function, the `id` is always as 0.

Comment: @Bigeyes what do you mean by "the `id` is always as 0"? You can pass id like `ng-click="delFn($index, emp.EmployeeId)"` and in controller.js the method should be like `$scope.delFn = function (index, id) { ... }` so you can call `EmployeeService.deleteEmployee(id);` inside.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash, please see the debugging information at [here](https://flic.kr/p/UihNy4).

Comment: @Bigeyes your `$scope.delFn` still uses only `$index` as argument, but I suggest you passing the employee id as well.

Comment: @Bigeyes take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9n90yof5/1/)  and see that id is passed to the controller's method from the view by calling `ng-click="delFn($index, emp.EmployeeId)"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.controller("EmpCtrl", ['$scope', 'EmployeeService', function ($scope, EmployeeService) {
//do stuff here
}]);
```

according to angular documentation, your service injection is not done correctly. Try to change controller to the above and see if the error is gone

Comment: i checked every line, the error indicates that EmployeeService is misspelled somewhere, but i cannot find where it is misspelled.